# WP - Ошибка обновления. Ответ не является допустимым ответом JSON + пропадает таблица из БД

Tags: html, wordpress, post, url

У меня появилась ошибка при обновлении информации на странице на сайте WordPress.

Ошибка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Консоль:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Network:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Также у меня почему-то из БД пропадает таблица с ссылками. Я проверял остальные и они работают(на примере таблица с ссылками и таблица с пользователями)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как исправить эту ошибку?

Comment: Сайт в подпапке? .htaccess правильный? https://wordpress.org/support/article/htaccess/ (Subfolder example)

Comment: Ну и плюс стандартная проверка - отключите все плагины, смените тему на стандартную и проверьте

Comment: @KAGGDesign https://ibb.co/R3tsJZv

Comment: Зачем вы мне эту картинку кидаете? Вы лучше прочтите, что я написал. И не один коммент, а оба.

Comment: @KAGGDesign где должен быть .htaccess?

Comment: @KAGGDesign у меня его вроде бы нету

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно сменить тип ссылок на простые(где ?page=1). Тогда пропадёт эта проблема.